# Qt C++ Изменить Ui с другого потока. Reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, ui

Есть функиця которая должна работать в цикле:

```
unsigned int __stdcall MainWindow::updating(void *data){
int last_change = 0;
while(1){
    Sleep(1);
    // код который в т.ч. меняет Ui
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Подключаю ее чтобы могла работать с ui:

```
private slots:
    unsigned int __stdcall updating(void *data);
```

И вызываю:

```
_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, updating, (void *)(&num), 0, &id);
```

Выбивает ошибку reference to non-static member function must be called.

Знаю что можно использовать QTimer, QThread и т.д. Но это для универа и нужно использовать именно чистую winapi функцию. Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: (1) Упакуйте указетль на MainWindow  и данные (&id) в одну структуру. (2) Передавайте  в статическую функцию указатель на эту струтуру, (3)  (внутри статической функции) распакуйте указатель и вызывайте нужный метод класса.

Comment: @Chorkov В любом случае если я через mainwindow меняю что-то в UI то получаю надпись в консоль QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread

Comment: В Qt нельзя изменять UI из другого потока. Можно вызвать обработчик в главном потоке, который будет менять UI. `_beginthreadex` это из CRT, winapi функция называется `CreateThread`.

Comment: Канонически в кьюте чтобы что-то в другом потоке меняло гуй, надо из другого потока испускать сигналы, соединенные с методами изменения элементов гуя